# Resource injection in webapplication JBoss 5

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

Is it possible to inject resources (like message queues, EJBs) using the @Resource annotation in webapplications running in JBoss 5? The webapp is part of an .ear file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why not try it and find out?

(ps: the answer is "yes")

Comment: Did not work after a week of trying so I turned to Stackoverflow. Just want to make sure I am not missing some poorly documented configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

What particular issue you have met with? I don't think 'Yes' or 'No' is what you want to be answered.

Comment: You are right. I expected something along the lines "works out of the box" or "put this and that in config file X". Solved the problem, the annotation does not work because the bean is not instantiated by JBoss but by Flex. I am going to close the question shortly.